# GELF logging driver with Windows Containers

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, gelf

I'm trying get an ELK stack up (Elastic Search, Logstash and Kibana) and would like to get the GELF logging driver to forward events to Logstash, however whenever I run my container with the specified driver I get `docker: Error response from daemon: logger: no log driver named 'gelf' is registered.` even though I'm on `1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta`. Is there a way to get this working on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 1):

The [supported log drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/supported-logging-drivers) section does list GELF (Graylog Extended Log Format), but by default on docker for Linux (so within a Linux VM on other platforms)

The [official GELF documention](http://docs.graylog.org/en/latest/pages/gelf.html) does recommend in [its installation page](http://docs.graylog.org/en/latest/pages/installation.html)

> Some modern Linux distribution (Debian Linux, Ubuntu Linux, or CentOS recommended)

So a Windows server 2016 might not include a Graylog server in its Docker.